# What is the benefit of angular.copy?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use angular.copy in some cases, like copying model default values to the form model, like this:

```
var customerModel = {
  name: '',
  point: 0
};

$scope.customer = angular.copy(customerModel);

function save() {
  //... Reset $scope.customer after success submit
  $scope.customer = angular.copy(customerModel);
}
```

... to prevent the default customerModel changed.

### But why copy empty object or array? {} or []

I found in some codes used angular.copy on empty object or array. Why they don't assign empty object directly to the variable?

```
$scope.customer = {}; // or [] for array
```

If you use copy on empty object or array, could you explain the benefit?

### What about ajax response ($http)?

And one more question, what did you do to ajax response? copy or assign it directly to a variable?

```
$http
  .get('example.com/api/v1/get/customer/1')
  .success(function(response) {
    $scope.customer = angular.copy(response.data);
    // or do you use $scope.customer = response.data ?
  })
;
```

And if you used copy, what do you think happened to the response object?
Is it remain in the memory? or deleted automatically?

Comment: maybe this can help [angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)

Comment: "Is it remain in the memory? or deleted automatically?" RE this, JavaScript uses a GC and as such it will be freed when that object is no longer used any more. This may or may not be after you `angular.copy()` it. It is non deterministic and you should not rely on it to trigger at any given time, but you should take care to ensure you don't create references that cannot be unwound by the GC.

Comment: For the memory question, as you're copying `response.data` and not `response` you don't know when `response` will be freed by GC as it may be used elsewhere.

Comment: @cespon not sure why this comment is necessary. as a tldr it gives you access to deep object copying without needing *another* library. Angular uses the copy internally which is why it is there.

Comment: I'm writing admin page with angular, and I want to make convention about handling $http response. So I need to make sure that after angular.copy(response.data), would the GC freed the object or not. And if not, I will prefer assign it directly to a $scope variable.

Comment: @Kiddo: these are two very different concerns: making stuff work and making it fast. What's up with this worry about GC? I'm willing to bet that it's not *really* a problem for you. Just something you picked up from the internets. Make your admin thing work, **then** memory-profile it.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to optimize the code, because it's a bit slow, maybe a lot. I'm also considering lazy load, because the total file size after minified is about 2MB. I'm still new to angular, so I try to tackle any kind of optimization.

Comment: You should find the source of your issue rather than blindly throwing optimizations at it. Are you sure your file is minified? That's a very large file size. I'm assuming that's including Angular and UI router being minified as well. If your issue is file size, GC isn't going to help you. Optimizing for GC is probably one of the last things you should do because it's so unlikely to help you (because GC is non deterministic)

Comment: response is an object, and response.data is a reference to another object... all is reference, if you use var a = response.data, when "response" is called for GC, the "data" object will stay because it's used by "a" variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You copy an object to prevent other code from modifying it. (original object might change, but your copy won't see the changes)

If you were to do this:

```
 $scope.customer = customerModel
```

... and some callback/service/whatnot changed `customerModel`, your scope would reflect this change. This is not always desirable, hence the need for deep copying.

#### Copying empty literal object

```
$scope.customer = angular.copy({})
// or
$scope.customer = {}
```

This doesn't make any difference. It's a new empty object every time. Note that it's very different from this:

```
this.customerModel = {};
$scope.customer = angular.copy(this.customerModel)
```

#### Copying ajax response data

Same rules apply. If you want to ensure that this object doesn't change from underneath you (which may happen if you also passed it to somewhere else, for example), you should copy it.

Comment: Copying an object does not prevent the modification of the original one

Comment: Of course. It prevents your copy from seeing the changes.

Comment: What about copy empty object or array? {} and [].

Comment: And what about ajax response, which one you prefer? copy or directly store to variable?

Comment: So, it would be okay if $scope.customer = angular.copy({}); changed with $scope.customer = {} ?

Comment: Yes, it won't make a difference.

Comment: Ajax response - depends. Sometimes I dispatch one response to different receivers. Some of them may run data transformations on it. Naturally, I don't want one receiver poison the others, so I copy, in this case.

Comment: @DanPantry: ah, indeed. Thought it's a variant of the first scenario. `this.customerModel = {}; $scope.customer = customerModel`

Comment: I edited the question to make the question clearer. @sergio I'll mark your answer as accepted if you don't mind to put your comment about empty object and ajax response to the answer.

Comment: @Kiddo: added the comments.

Answer (score 3):

angular.copy creates deep copy of variable so that it would hold the reference of another variable

sometimes it happens when user dont want to use call by reference then deep copy comes in action According to your question

```
var customerModel = {
  name: '',
  point: 0
};
```

If you will use `$scope.customer = angular.copy(customerModel);` it will create deep copy of customerModel

As far as $http Service is concerned .Data is coming from response and If you you will assign It directly then there would be no effect of call by reference because data is coming from another source. 
So I would rather assign it directly in case of $http.get()

Comment: I edited the question to make it clearer. Hope you don't mind to see it again. Thank you.